# fixed draggable Scrollbar or Scrubber with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, scrollbar

I want to achieve the exact same as this website http://energytrust.org/timeline/ as in they have a bar at the bottom with a handle you drag to scroll the page..
[image]

I cant seem to find anything

Comment: I thin Kendo-ui slider will do http://demos.kendoui.com/web/slider/index.html

Answer (score 0):

----------------------------------**EXAMPLE #1**

So as I mentioned in a comment  - Kendo-ui slider [Kendo-ui slider](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/slider/index.html) will do.
Here is an example [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DLrBk/)

Basically I made the content wider then the screen and then moved it on slider's "slide" event via changing it's margin.

**NOTE:** this is not the only way to do this. Just an example.

**HTML**

```
<div id="main"></div>
<input id="slider" class="balSlider" value="0" />
```

**Css**:

```
#main {
    width:2000px;
    height:200px;
    background: #1e5799;
    /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #1e5799 0%, #29b221 25%, #d83a22 77%, #f2f282 100%);
    /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, #1e5799), color-stop(25%, #29b221), color-stop(77%, #d83a22), color-stop(100%, #f2f282));
    /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #1e5799 0%, #29b221 25%, #d83a22 77%, #f2f282 100%);
    /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #1e5799 0%, #29b221 25%, #d83a22 77%, #f2f282 100%);
    /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #1e5799 0%, #29b221 25%, #d83a22 77%, #f2f282 100%);
    /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #1e5799 0%, #29b221 25%, #d83a22 77%, #f2f282 100%);
    /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#f2f282', GradientType=1);
    /* IE6-9 */
}
```

**Javascript**:

```
var slider = $("#slider").kendoSlider({
    increaseButtonTitle: "Right",
    decreaseButtonTitle: "Left",
    slide: sliderOnSlide,
    min: 0,
    max: 20,
    smallStep: 2,
    largeStep: 1
}).data("kendoSlider");

function sliderOnSlide(e) {
    $("#main").css("margin-left", "-" + (e.value * 20)+"px");
}
```

----------------------**Example #2**

You can use [Custom scroll bar plugin](https://github.com/mzubala/jquery-custom-scrollbar) to achieve the same.
Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n8T6w/1/)

**HTML**

```
<body class="container default-skin">
<div id="main" ></div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body
{
 height:202px;
    width:300px;

}

#main {
    width:2000px;
    height:200px;
    background: #1e5799;
    /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #1e5799 0%, #29b221 25%, #d83a22 77%, #f2f282 100%);
    /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, #1e5799), color-stop(25%, #29b221), color-stop(77%, #d83a22), color-stop(100%, #f2f282));
    /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #1e5799 0%, #29b221 25%, #d83a22 77%, #f2f282 100%);
    /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #1e5799 0%, #29b221 25%, #d83a22 77%, #f2f282 100%);
    /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #1e5799 0%, #29b221 25%, #d83a22 77%, #f2f282 100%);
    /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #1e5799 0%, #29b221 25%, #d83a22 77%, #f2f282 100%);
    /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#f2f282', GradientType=1);
    /* IE6-9 */
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".container").customScrollbar();
});
```